# Regex pattern not working on my C# code however it works on an online tester

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract the double value from the string that contains a specific keyword. For example:

> Amount : USD 3,747,190.67

I need to extract the value "3,747,190.67" from the string above using the keyword Amount, for that I tested this pattern in different online Regex testers and it works:

```
(?<=\bAmount.*)(\d+\,*\.*)*
```

However it doesn't work on my C# code:

```
if (type == typeof(double))
{
    double doubleVal = 0;
    pattern = @"(?<=\bAmount.*)(\d+\,*\.*)*";
    matchPattern = Regex.Match(textToParse, pattern);

    if (matchPattern.Success)
    {
        double.TryParse(matchPattern.Value.ToString(), out doubleVal);
    }
    return doubleVal;
}
```

Comment: Please show your C# code.

Comment: It's [not working](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbAmount.%29%28%5cd%2b%2c.%29&i=Amount+%3a+USD+3%2c747%2c190.67) with an online tester for me.

Comment: Also, please format your question, it's difficult to read. And also show us it working in the online Regex testers (because it's not working for me)

Comment: Especially pay attention to using the code sample tool whilst pasting a regex into your question. At the moment, some of the characters are being picked up as markdown formatting instructions and whilst someone else can try to recover the original code it would be a lot easier for you to supply it in exactly the right state.

Comment: I used these links to do my tests http://regexstorm.net/tester and https://rextester.com/tester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lookbehind `(?<=\bAmount.*)` is always true in the example data after Amount.

The first 7 matches are empty, as `(\d+\,*\.*)*` can not consume a character where there is no digit, but it matches at the position as the quantifier `*` matches 0 or more times.

See this screenshot of the matches:

[image]

You might use

```
(?<=\bAmount\D*)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\b
```

- `(?<=\bAmount\D*)` Positive lookbehind, assert Amount to the left followed by optional non digits
- `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
- `(?:,\d{3})*` Optionally repeat `,` and 3 digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` Optionally match `.` and 1 or 2 digits
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbAmount%5cD*%29%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%28%3f%3a%2c%5cd%7b3%7d%29*%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%29%3f%5cb&i=Amount+%3a+USD+3%2c747%2c190.67)

For example

```
double doubleVal = 0;
var pattern = @"(?<=\bAmount\D*)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\b";
var textToParse = "Amount : USD 3,747,190.67";
var matchPattern = Regex.Match(textToParse, pattern);
if (matchPattern.Success)
{
    double.TryParse(matchPattern.Value.ToString(), out doubleVal);
}
Console.WriteLine(doubleVal);
```

Output

```
3747190.67
```

You can omit the word boundaries if needed if a partial match is also valid

```
(?<=Amount\D*)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?
```

Comment: I'm using activebatch email trigger, so when I receive an email with a specific subject, activebatch will send the email body as a parameter to my application and then I will parse the body and extract the necessary values and dates. The problem is that the body is sent as one sentence (no separation between lines \n) and the patterns posted in comments didn't work for me. Example : `Dear all,Please be informed that we will increase the NAV Fund - PIPAmount : USD 1,031,299.03Old allocated assets total : USD 386,235,863.55New estimated* allocated assets total : USD 387,267,162.58`

Comment: @GtariAbir Try omitting the word boundary `(?<=Amount\D*)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\b` https://regex101.com/r/swdmab/1

Comment: Thank you that worked, I just removed \b in the end `(?<=Amount\D*)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?`

Comment: Could you please help me to extract the date? I'm trying this pattern `(?<=\bNAV date.*)[0-9]{2}-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-[0-9]{2}`  for example: `New estimated* allocated assets total : USD 419,511,676.33Reference NAV date : 14-Jun-21Value date :               17-Jun-21Please adjust the trading level no later than 15-Jun-21.`

Comment: @GtariAbir Just a single date? https://regex101.com/r/QvwARB/1

Comment: yes please, just a single date, for example if I use the keyword NAV date  the result should be 14-Jun-21, if I use Value date the result should be 17-Jun-21 and if I use the keyword no later than, the result should be 15-Jun-21

Comment: This will be Value date https://regex101.com/r/k98cjv/1/ and neither of the patterns matches, you can just match the date format https://regex101.com/r/9ydP5k/1

Answer (score 2):

This one works:

```regex
(?<=\bAmount.*)\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+)?
```

- `(?<=\bAmount.*)` the look behind
- `\d+`                       leading digits (at least one digit)
- `(,\d+)*`                thousands groups (zero or more times)
- `(\.\d+)?`              decimals (`?` = optional)

Note that the regex tester says "**9 matches found**" for your pattern. For my pattern it says "**1 match found**".

The problem with your pattern is that its second part `(\d+\,*\.*)*` can be empty because of the `*` at the end. The `*` quantifier means zero, one or more repetitions. Therefore, the look-behind finds 8 empty entries between `Amount` and the number. The last of the 9 matches is the number. You can correct it by replacing the `*` with a `+`. See: [regextester with *](https://rextester.com/tester/KANLU37030), [regextester with +](https://rextester.com/tester/HLYG77399). You can also test it with "your" tester and switch to the table to see the detailed results.

My solution does not allow consecutive commas or points but allows numbers without thousands groups or a decimal part.